# How to place ReCaptcha on my squarespace site form?

Tags: recaptcha

I'm trying to place a Recaptcha on my squarespace form but to do so I need a 'site key' and a 'secret key'... but when I create a 'key', it only gives me 1 key: site id key. How do I get both keys for my form?

Answer (score 1):

To create the correct pair of keys, log on to your Squarespace website and go to **Settings** > **Advanced** > **External API Keys** > **Google reCAPTCHA**.

From there, you'll need a Google account.

The link will open a new tab where you can log on to your Google account.

Click **v3 Admin Console**, enter a nickname for your site, choose **reCAPTCHA V2** and provide the domain names for your site (both the public one and the one you use to edit the site).

When you've submitted all the correct details, Google will provide you with both keys:

[Screenshot of keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsCjg.png)